# CSS3 Styling text transform for multiple words

Tags: css, css-transforms

```
<li><a>BACKGROUND SCORE</a></li>

i would like to transform this word into

<li><a>Background Score</a></li>

i have tried this

li>a { text-transform: lowercase }
li>a:first-letter { text-transform: capitalize}
```

bt output is changes only frst word of frst letter

```
<li><a>Background score</a></li>
```

Comment: That's the way `capitalize` works. It just capitalizes the first letter of each word in the selected text. In your case, all letters are already capitalized, it remains unchanged. You would need to use Javascript to do sentence-casing if your original text is already upper-case.

Comment: remove the :first-letter -  If what Abhitalks says is true, then maybe you can lowercase the <li> and capitalize the <a>?

Answer (score 0):

Try do it that way:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <style>
        li>a { text-transform: lowercase;
        display: inline-block;}
li>a:first-letter { text-transform: capitalize;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <li><a>BACKGROUND SCORE</a></li>            
    </body>

</html>
```

You will get what you want.